# Problems Accessing Azure Graph API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I am having some trouble with a MVC .net application that i am writing. I have it linked to our internal AD so that people can log in. But i would like them to be able to reset their office 365 passwords using the graph api for azure. The internal AD and office 365 are not linked and i am having trouble finding anything that helps me build the connection from scratch in the new controller that i added.

The code i have in my controller is:

```
public ActionResult ChangePassword()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangeEmailPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var user = FindUser(User.Identity.GetUserName());

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "password", model.NewPassword },
                { "forceChangePasswordNextLogin", "false" }
            };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

            var url = "https://graph.windows.net/162035a0-31d1-4b3c-a276-491c1dbea2f1/users/" + user.EmailAddress + "?api-version=1.6";

            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = responseString;
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    #region Helpers

    public UserPrincipal FindUser(string userName)
    {
        var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["adInternalDomainFull"], WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["adInternalDomain"], WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["adInternalAdminUser"], WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["adInternalAdminPassword"]);
        var userAccount = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, userName);

        return userAccount;
    }

    #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this code is doing, but have you tried using Graph Client Library for doing this?